# Connection to localhost

Tags: localhost, wampserver

I installed wampserver on my computer, and like usual I had an port issue, so I changed the port on the Httpd file, from 80 to 8080

Even wampserver is started, green icone, I must everytime add :8080 to my localhost link

Is it normal, or i must change something else

Thank's  a lot

Answer (score 0):

Thats normal.

Everything expects a web server to be listening on port 80, and therefore everything defaults to that. If you change the port that your web server listens on then you have to tell ervything NOT TO use the default.

Its a major pain.

It is a much better idea to fix whatever is causing the problem with port 80 so you can run your webserver on that port.

Most things can be re-configured so that they leave port 80 alone.

Use this WAMP fucntion to find what is using port 80.

```
left click the wampmanager icon ( thats the W icon in the system tray )
left click the wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Test port 80
```

Then reconfigure whatever it reports as using port 80. If you dont know how to, then ask another question. Someone will know how to.

Comment: HI RiggsFolly and thanks for your response.

I tried the test port before, and I forget to tell you it used by IIS service I thought since I changed the port on wamp, why i will change again the port of IIS service. I just want to when i click on localhost on wampservice, I will go directly to Localhost:8080

Comment: Are you actually using IIS?

Comment: No, I don't, but even I don't use IIS, why I should remove him, I think it's better for me to fix the issue with Wamp ?

Comment: Well how about this. IIS is using resource on your PC purely because microsoft decided to install it by default. Thats wasted memory and CPU cycles. It listens on port 80 and therefore will respond to requests from there. Do you have any idea how secure it is, or what it will do by default? It is basically another attack vector on your PC  for hackers, and you ( and most of the rest of us ) have no idea how to maintain it or make sure it is secure. It is a complex and fully featured web server and therefore should be maintained by someone with knowledge and experience.

Comment: If you dont want to uninstall it then at least I would suggest `disabling` all its services. You get back PC resource and can use the proper port 80 for the webserver you are actively looking at and maintaining, hopefully in a secure way.

Comment: I think that you are right, I am wasting with a fake problem, I don't even start my website, I will remove IIS as you advice me, and get my focus on other issue, in the future if i will be faced with IIS problems i will find the solution, thank's a lot